Upload Folder in Sharepoint Document using Graph API in C#
How can I create folder new folder and upload new folder in SharePoint Document Library using Graph API in C#?
I want to create a folder and also If I have one folder and in that folder I have 5 files. so I need to upload that folder with that all 5 files.
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Sites.GetAllSites;

namespace UploadFiles;
public class GraphHandler
{
    public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

    public GraphHandler(string tenantId, string clientId, string clienSecret)
    {
        GraphClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clienSecret);
    }

    public GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var option = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        var clientSecretCredentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, option);
        var scope = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredentials, scope);
    }
}

I am trying to using Graph handler that i mentioned above.
how can I do this?

To create the folder on SharePoint using c# sharp you could follow this document:
Create a new folder in a drive
To upload multiple files to the folder use this method:
public async Task<DriveItem> UploadFilesAsync(string siteId, string libraryId, string folderPath, string fileName, Stream fileStream)
{
    string path = $":/{folderPath}/{fileName}:/content";

    try
    {
        return await GraphClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[libraryId].Root.ItemWithPath(path).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}

Here is the another reference you could check. you could loop to upload the files:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1110415/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-sharepoint-using-g
To upload the folder:
public async Task UploadFolderAsync(string siteId, string libraryId, string localFolderPath, string remoteFolderPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(localFolderPath);
    foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await UploadFileToFolderAsync(siteId, libraryId, remoteFolderPath, file.Name, stream);
        }
    }
}

you could use these method in your code for example : await graphHandler.CreateFolderAsync("site-id", "root", "NewFolder");. make sure you have assigned permission like Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All on azure.
